# How to customize a Bad Request response in Firebase functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I wrote a simple Firebase function like below

```
exports.simpleFunc = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    
    try{
        JSON.parse(req.body);
        res.send('Valid');
    }
    catch(error){
        res.send('JSON is invalid');
    }
});
```

then I ran this function locally by using `firebase emulator:start`

after that I used Postman to test this function by sending an invalid JSON values

```
{
    "firstName": "User 1",
    "email": "abc@mail.com",
    "description": "\u000g" >> this is an invalid value
}
```

I expect that my function should return my error message `JSON is invalid`. However it returned a whole HTML page with an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token g in JSON at position xx at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`

So my question is: **How can I send my error message instead of the whole HTML string?**

I have found the same issue here
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/364

But it's not my expectation.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can expect to catch the error parsing of JSON if you declared it as JSON. To catch it, instead of declaring as JSON, declare it as text and parse it on the client. See images below for reference.

Declaring it as **`JSON`** (See green highlighted section):
[image]

Declaring it as **`Text`** (See green highlighted section):
[image]